# Always getting NotReadableError from FileReader

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, filereader

In my Cordova app, I am constantly getting a NotReadableError from FileReader regardless of which file I select.

This is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" onchange="selectedFileChanged(event)"/>
```

...

```
function selectedFileChanged(event){
    var file=event.target.files[0];
    if(file){
        var reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend=function(event){
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself. It is a permission error.

```
var permissions=cordova.plugins.permissions;
function getPermissions(){
    permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, function(status){
        if(!status.hasPermission){
            console.log(status);
            return;
        }
        var reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend=function(event){
            //$('#openingDimmer').css('display','none');
            console.log(event);
            console.log(this);
            if(event.target.result){
                console.log(event.target.result);
            }else{
                ons.notification.alert(event.target.error);
            }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    },function(){
        console.log('error');
    });
}
setTimeout(getPermissions,0);
```